# How can I split the text by semicolon in Column A and and make key/value in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with 500 values in column A. I am looking for a formula to split the text in column A by semicolon and then append index(starting from 1) and then equal to sign and then the text.
e.g 1=aaa.....

Text in Column A:
aaa.;bbb.;ccc.

Desired Output:
1=aaa.;2=bbb.;3=ccc.

I am looking for a formula like the following in JavaScript:

```
console.log("aaa.;bbb.;ccc.".split(";").map((element, index) => (index+1)+'='+element.trim()).join(';'));
```

Comment: Tried the text to columns function or left() and find()?

Comment: Also what version do you have?

Comment: I have Microsoft office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in all versions of 365:

```
=LET(cel,A1,arr,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(cel,";",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(cel)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(cel,";",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),TEXTJOIN(";",,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(arr))&"="&arr))
```

[image]

If using a PC then we can use FILTERXML:

```
=LET(cel,A1,arr,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(cel,";","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),TEXTJOIN(";",,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(arr))&"="&arr))
```

[image]

Also there is a new function, currently in beta that we can use called TEXTSPLIT:

```
LET(cel,A1,arr,TEXTSPLIT(cel,";"),TEXTJOIN(";",,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(arr))&"="&arr))
```

Comment: You code works thanks. 
I need one more favour: I need another formula for a blank option in the beginning as well. 
Example Text in Column A: ;aaa.;bbb.;ccc.
Desired Output: 0=;1=aaa.;2=bbb.;3=ccc.

Comment: Adding additional needs to the question after getting an answer that satisfies the need original asked for is not according to the rules of this forum.  Please as ask a new question with the new criteria, be sure to show what you tried.

Comment: I am not an Excel developer. I just need it for 1 time text conversions.

Comment: You just need to ask a new question and someone will help you with it.  Feel free to link back to this question.